# Xpath unable to find calendar element in webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make selenium find and click the different times on the webapge https://www.macengsociety.ca/hatch-booking-1/h201/book. I have a sleep timer to load the whole page, then I even scroll down, then I use pynput to click on the date I want, but I cant make selenium finder locate any of the times available.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time from pynput.mouse import Button, 
Controller driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\abdoo\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get('macengsociety.ca/hatch-booking-1/h201/book') 
time.sleep(5) 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080)") 
time.sleep(1) 
mouse = Controller() 
mouse.position = (340, 475) 
mouse.click(Button.left, 1) 
time.sleep(1) 
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/bks-app/div/div[1]/boost-calendar-page/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/boost-time-slots-list[3]/li/div[2]/span") 
elem.click() –
```

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\abdoo\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.macengsociety.ca/hatch-booking-1/h201/book')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080)")
time.sleep(1)
mouse = Controller()
mouse.position = (340, 475)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
time.sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/bks-app/div/div[1]/boost-calendar-page/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/boost-time-slots-list[3]/li/div[2]/span")
elem.click()

Comment: Please add your comment to the question and make sure it's in a code block. It would help!

Comment: To follow @Chrips comment, use the [edit] link under your post to update it. Then format your code by selecting it and clicking on the `{ }` button. See the **Code Blocks** section of the [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). As you can see, codes in comments is unreadable.